# Speech Recognition não funciona

Tags: c#, reconhecimento-de-voz

Por que a o *speech Recognition* não funciona no Windows 7 nem no Windows 10.

Desenvolvi pelo código de exemplo da Microsoft e não funcionou, achei esse código na internet que mostra ele funcionando no PC da pessoa e ele também não funcionou.

Instalado aqui:

- speeach recognition language-tele(pt-br) speeach text to speech
- voice(pt-br heloisa) speech platform sdk x86 v11.0 server speech
- platform runtime (x64)

Windows 7 x64 e do meu outro PC é Windows 10 x86.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
namespace reconocimiento2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = false;
            button3.Visible = false;
            Choices lista = new Choices();

            lista.Add(new string []{"amarelo","azul","vermelho","todos","nenhum","sair"});

                Grammar gramatica = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(lista));
                try
                {
                    rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                    rec.LoadGrammar(gramatica);
                    rec.SpeechRecognized += reconocimento;
                    rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

                }
                catch (Exception) 
                {

                    throw;
                }
        }
        void reconocimento(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) 
        {
            if(e.Result.Text=="amarelo")
            {
                button1.Visible = true;
            }else
                if(e.Result.Text=="azul")
            {
                button2.Visible = true;
            }else
               if(e.Result.Text=="vermelho")
            {
                button3.Visible = true;
            }else

              if(e.Result.Text=="todos")
            {
                button1.Visible = true;
                button2.Visible = true;
                button3.Visible = true;
            }else
             if(e.Result.Text=="nenhum")
            {
                button1.Visible = false;
                button2.Visible = false;
                button3.Visible = false;
            }else
                  if(e.Result.Text=="sair")
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: qual o erro que isso deu?? e qual a sua dificuldade?

Comment: O computador nao reconhece o comando de voz de geito nenhum. Eu falo e nada acontece. Como se ele nao reconhecesse.

Comment: Você depurou? Na sua função "reconocimento" tem um monte de `if`s específicos. Você verificou o que *de fato* está sendo "reconhecido" (isto é, imprimou o valor recebido nessa função)? Faça ao menos essa lição de casa, senão fica realmente difícil alguém conseguir te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

solucionei instalando o pack ingles e ativando ele no pc pack ingles language,
obrigado a todos que comentou! :D